# Weird java foreign key constraint failure when running unit tests

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, unit-testing

So I've recently been hitting my head against the wall because of a problem I have when I try to unit test my services.

I have a User which has multiple unidirectional relationships to the Product, Customer and Quotation classes.
I use SpringBoot with the Spring JPA repositories to perform operations to the MySQL database using Hibernate as ORM.

I also have different services which call the repositories to perform these actions to the database, and it are these that I am trying to unit test.

When I run my unit test classes separately they all succeed without problems, but when I run them all together the QuotationService tests fail completely. Noteworthy however is that they always run after the CustomerService tests.

After looking at the stacktrace I found out that every test fails because of a foreign key constraint when I try to save a quotation to the database in the testclass.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kmobeheerdb`.`quotation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_fq5x6je1sicnskcj35yqhp85g` FOREIGN KEY (`quotation_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:683)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:108)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2061)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1819)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2033)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1969)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:4953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1954)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
... 105 more
```

The part of the tests where they always fail is in the @Before section, when I try to save a new quotation.

```
@Autowired private QuotationService quotationService;
    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    private User user;
    private Quotation quotation;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws UserServiceException, QuotationServiceException {
        String userEmail = "tzestermail@mail.com";
        String userName = "testername";

        User newUser = new User(userEmail, userName);
        user = userService.register(newUser);

        //Tests fail on the createQuotation statement beneath
        Quotation newQuotation = new Quotation();
        quotation = quotationService.createQuotation(newQuotation, user.getUserId()); 

        user = userService.getUser(user.getUserId());

        assertNotNull(user);
        assertNotNull(quotation);
        assertEquals(1, user.getQuotations().size());
    }
```

I searched around a lot to try and solve this issue, including making the relations bidirectional, but nothing really worked and the error persisted.

**For reference:**

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "UX_user_email", columnNames = {"email"})
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int userId;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "productId", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Product> products;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "quotationId", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Quotation> quotations;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customerId", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Customer> customers;

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public void addQuotation(Quotation quotation){
        if(quotation != null){
            if(quotations == null){
                quotations = new HashSet<>();
            }
            quotations.add(quotation);
        }
    }

    public void removeQuotation(Quotation quotation){
        if(quotation != null && quotations.contains(quotation)){
            quotations.remove(quotation);
        }
    }

    //Omitted getters and setters
}
```

Quotation class:

```
@Entity
public class Quotation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "quotation_id", nullable = false)
    private int quotationId;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "productId", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Product> products;

    private double routeTotal;
    private double total;
    private String memo;

    //Omitted getters and setters
}
```

Quotation Service:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = QuotationServiceException.class)
@Service
public class QuotationServiceImpl implements QuotationService {
    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    @Autowired private ExceptionStrings exceptionStrings;
    @Autowired private UserService userService;
    @Autowired private QuotationRepository quotationRepository;

    @Override
    public Quotation createQuotation(Quotation quotation, int userId) throws QuotationServiceException {
        if (quotation == null || userId == 0 || userService.getUser(userId) == null) {
            logger.error(exceptionStrings.createQuotationInputError);
            throw new QuotationServiceException(exceptionStrings.createQuotationInputError);
        }
        try {
            User user = userService.getUser(userId);
            user.addQuotation(quotation);
            return quotationRepository.save(quotation);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            logger.error(exceptionStrings.createQuotationError);
            throw new QuotationServiceException(exceptionStrings.createQuotationError, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a lot of code, please try to narrow it down to a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if possible.

Comment: Side note: for unit tests, you should probably mock any database calls, and only use a database for integration / acceptance tests.

Comment: If your tests work well separately but fail when run together, then this usually indicates an issue with the test data. Are you reversing any changes that are made by each test? Specifically, are you resetting the database before *each test*, or only once per test run?

Comment: @ScottWeldon thanks for the feedback, I have narrowed down my code parts a bit to make it more viewable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I found a solution to the problem. As Scott Weldon suggested I checked if my database got reset every run. My hibernate was configured to create-drop, but it seems I also needed to force the Spring configuration to reload by placing

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

above each test class.

This fixed the problem for me.